# Is there any reason to use generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Perhaps I'm missing the point but coming from a C# background, I can't see any reason to use Java's generics...

In C# I've got a method which takes a string and deserializes it into an object...

```
public static Deserialize<T>(string source) {
    // Use reflection to examine T and determine
    // which properties I should be reading from
    // the string. Create an instance of T, 
    // populate the properties and return it
}
```

which I can call as follows: `x.Deserialize<AnyClass>("String representation of AnyClass");`

Type erasure seems to make this impossible in Java?

My next most common usage of generics is storing things in lists but since I can't do `List<int>` and have to box to use `List<Integer>`, it seems like pointless overhead boxing/unboxing when I could just use `int[]`.

So... Is the only real use for generics to do things like

```
List<MyClass> MyClassList = new List<MyClass>
```

and get some compile-time type checking? If so, it seems pretty redundant given that the variable name makes it clear what the type should be (at least as long as I'm using sensible naming conventions).

I can't help but feel I'm missing something...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, if you don't use generics, you get to cast each time. You would have to:

```
// if raw List
MyClass c = (MyClass) myClassList.get(0);
// if List<MyClass>
MyClass c = myClassList.get(0);
```

for instance.

Yes, generics are erased at runtime, yes, they are here to enforce type safety at compile time only; however there is still runtime type erasure when you use bounds. Example:

```
public <E extends RuntimeException> E get(final Class<E> c,
    final Throwable t)
{
    try {
        return (E) getHandle(c).invokeExact(t);
    } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Throwable oops) {
        final RuntimeException exception = new IllegalStateException(oops);
        exception.addSuppressed(t);
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

The `E` here has a runtime type erasure; it `extends RuntimeException`. Therefore the cast is to `RuntimeException`, not `Object`.

See the [javadoc of `Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) for another interesting example of runtime type erasure (hint: why does it define `T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>` instead of `T extends Comparable<? super T>`?)

Comment: Interesting point re: bounds, but it means you're always aiming for the lowest common denominator. What if you wanted to be able to Compare _and_ (Count)? Comparable works because it's widely-used by every class out there that's comparable. If you want to have 2 such methods, you'd need your classes to inherit from `MyComparableCountable` which limits you to classes you've implemented...

Comment: Well, I don't know what you mean by `Count`; note that you when you `extends E1 & E2 & etc`, the second parameter and further must be interfaces. If your `Count` is a concrete class then writing `T extends Count & Comparable<? super T>` will work, and you'll be able to use the result as both a `Count` and a `Comparable`. This check is, again, at compile time, and the compiler will emit the appropriate code so that you don't get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Count was probably a bad example. I was trying to pick another method that might exist on multiple classes but not all. Are you saying I can chain as many "features" together as I need... `Count & Comparable & SomethingElse<? super T>`?

Comment: "I was trying to pick another method that might exist on multiple classes" <-- not sure what you mean here? As to "feature chaining" (I can't pinpoint an accurate name for it), to be really honest I don't know whether there's an upper limit; I have only ever needed two maximum at a time ;)

Comment: `&` in type bound creates an *intersection type*.

Answer (score 3):

From the Java Docs :

### Why Use Generics?

In a nutshell, generics enable types (classes and interfaces) to be parameters when defining classes, interfaces and methods. Much like the more familiar formal parameters used in method declarations, type parameters provide a way for you to re-use the same code with different inputs. The difference is that the inputs to formal parameters are values, while the inputs to type parameters are types.

Code that uses generics has many benefits over non-generic code:

- Stronger type checks at compile time.
  A Java compiler applies strong type checking to generic code and issues errors if the code violates type safety. Fixing compile-time errors is easier than fixing runtime errors, which can be difficult to find.
- Elimination of casts.
  The following code snippet without generics requires casting:

  ```
  List list = new ArrayList();
  list.add("hello");
  String s = (String) list.get(0);
  ```

  When re-written to use generics, the code does not require casting:

  ```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("hello");
  String s = list.get(0); // no cast
  ```
- Enabling programmers to implement generic algorithms.
  By using generics, programmers can implement generic algorithms that work on collections of different types, can be customized, and are type safe and easier to read.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, but that's all just compile-time sugar. The real power of generics in other languages is their use at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Generic Types are checked in compile time only but it can be helpful to avoid bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Deserialize` method is not impossible in Java. You just have to explicitly pass the `Class` object because it cannot be determined at runtime from the type parameter `T`.

```
public static <T> T deserialize(Class<T> clazz, String source) {
    // Use reflection to examine clazz and determine
    // which properties I should be reading from
    // the String. Create an instance of T 
    // (which you can do using clazz.newInstance()), 
    // populate the properties and return it
}
```

It can be called using `deserialize(AnyClass.class, "String representation of AnyClass")`.

Comment: Nice suggestion but doesn't this fail if the class I'm deserializing has properties which are generic? Eg I can't determine, even from your `clazz` what that generic parameter is? Upvoting for the workaround

Comment: Yes it does fail in that case. That is the one area where I will concede C# is MUCH better.

Answer (score 1):

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("car");
list.add("cycle");
list.add(12);
```

Here list can contain any object , it can be String,Integer or double, Employee etc
which can cause type safety problem and stops runtime errors at compile time.

```
List<String> list  = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Here, only string values can be added

Comment: That would be the `So... Is the only real use for generics to do things like ... and get some compile-time type checking?` I mentioned in my original post?

Comment: Ya it avoids ClassCastException and are type safe

Comment: My question was more about _using_ the type information at run time - eg to serialise an object using its type information to enumerate parameters . In any case, this is a moot point for me at I've managed to move away from Java, but by all means leave this in case others interpreter my question the same way and find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyClass> MyClassList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

is not equivalent to:

```
List MyClassList = new ArrayList();
```

the second one will work on Object type, and you will be allowed to do something stupid like MyClassList.add(new Integer(0));

This is one of the major strengths of generics, or templates in C++. Compile time check that verifies your application that it will not do any undefined behaviour - like in above example.

Comment: Maybe I'm lucky but I've never worked with developers that incompetent. Sure another check is nice but... If someone is making mistakes like that, I don't want them working on my codebase

Comment: @Basic maybe my example is a little too drastic, in complicated and large code bases type checking is helpfull - this is just another tool to help developers in finding bugs. This is like a debate whether to use asserts in java or always throw Exceptions.

Comment: I can attest from my experience with dynamic languages (Clojure mostly) that it is a great pain to track down what a collection holds, especially when your code regularly works with similar representations of the same concept (like DB IDs, full entity objects, simplified special-purpose hashes, and so on). All such collections would typically use the same name.