# Example of usage arrays as generic parameter

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Recently I learn that arrays in Java are an object type.

So we can write them as a generic parameters:

```
public class Main implements Comparable<int[]> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(int[] o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In which practical cases we can use arrays in such way and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any reason to use generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689669/is-there-any-reason-to-use-generics-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In which practical cases we can use arrays in such [a] way and why?

Well, I would ask in return: "In what practical cases can we use, say, `Integer`in such way and why?"  Or `String`? Or `Person`?  Or *whatever* class?

The answer is simple: You *can* use **any** class as a generic type parameter, so use whatever class makes sense for your particular application.

If you're looking for a concrete example: you could have a `Map` that associates each key word with a list (in the form of an array) of synonyms:

```
    Map<String,String[]> synonyms = new Map<>();
    synonyms.put("green", 
                 new String[]{"emerald", "verdant", "inexperienced"});
    synonyms.put("friend",
                 new String[]{"pal","comrade","buddy","mate","ally"});
    // etc.
```

Of course, whether or not a `Map<String,String[]>` makes sense for this particular application comes down to requirements analysis.  `Map<String,String[]>` is really not optimal except in the case where the `synonyms` table will be set up during application start-up and never (or seldom) updated again.  For update-on-the-fly capability, a `Map<String,List<String>?` or `Map<String,Set<String>>` might be better.  But if `Map<String,String[]>` satisfies your needs, it's perfectly reasonable to use it.